# Showing $u_1, u_2, u_3$ is basis

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ be a basis for a vector space $V$. I want to show that $\{u1, u2, u3\}$ is also a basis where $u1 = v1, u2 = v1 + v2$ and $u3 = v1 + v2 + v3$

I wanted to use the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$ for vectors $v1, v2, v3$ to prove this as it is a know basis. So using $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$ which are a basis for $\mathbb R^3$ then $u1 = v1 = (100)$, $u2 = v1 + v2 = (1, 1, 0)$ and $u3 = v1 + v2 + v3 = (1, 1, 1)$

Then performing guassian elimination would trivially result in the identity matrix for $\mathbb R^3$ and finding it's determinant would be non-zero (1). Therefore $\{u1, u2, u3\}$ would be linearly independent and span $\mathbb R^3$ and so it too is a basis for the vector space $V$.

Is this the correct way to show this and is my choice to use the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb R^3$ suitable or does it need to be more general?

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to do this. you have a basis  $V=\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}.$ we nee to show that $U=\{v_1, v_1 + v_2, v_1 + v_2 + v_3 \}$ is a basis.  we will show that  $U$ is linearly independent. that should prove that $U$ is a basis.

suppose $$xv_1 + y(v_1 + v_2) + z (v_1 + v_2 + v_3)= 0\tag 1$$ we can rewrite this as $(x+y+z)v_1 + (y+z)v_2 + zv_3= 0.$  now, use the fact that $V$ is a basis to conclude that $$z = 0, y+z = 0\to y = 0, x+y+z = 0\to x = 0.\tag 2$$

we have shown that $(1)$ implies $(2).$ that means $U$ is a basis.

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler than what you do: since $\{v_1, v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis by hypothesis, it is enough to prove $v_1, v_2,v_3$ can be expressed with $u_1, u_2, u_3$. This will prove $\{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$ is a set of generators and  as we're in dimension $3$, it's a basis.

Indeed $\, v_1=u_1$, $v_2=u_2-v_1=u_2-u_1\,$ and$\,v_3=u_3-v_1-v_2=u_3-u_2$.